# Facebook app requests and invites taking too much time to load

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

I have a mobile gaming application.I have developed it in cocos2d.I noticed recently that sometimes when i am trying to send the non-app requests the facebook web page is taking time to load. This problem was not happening before 2nd week of march 2017. This problem was recently introduced and some of the users of the app are facing this problem. Please provide the possible solutions i can look into.

Comment: Look into [ask] first of all, please.

Comment: Sorry @CBroe. I have edited the question. Can you please help me now.